# Как запретить редакторам гугл таблицы создавать новые листы?

Tags: google-spreadsheet, таблицы, защита

Есть гугл таблица я владелец, доступ имеют по ссылке 15+ человек в роли редакторов. Проблема в следующем: у всех у них есть право создавать новые листы! они просто клацают на "плюсик" типо добавить новый лист, в итоге потом в таблице куча пустых листов, они также могут создать копию основного листа/переименовать/удалить/перемещать/..вообщем бред.. когда заходишь в таблицу твориться хаос, какой смысл тогда защищать диапазоны, если любой пользователь может создать копию основного листа, переместить его на передний план и там уже диапазоны не будут защищены. **Лист в этой таблице должен быть только один основной!** **и ни у кого не должно быть права кроме владельца создавать и прочее вышеуказанное** Есть ли способ **запретить** другим пользователям создавать/перемещать/переименовывать листы? Заранее благодарю..

Comment: Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31187470/prevent-user-from-adding-a-new-sheet-in-google-spreadsheet) показывается программа, которая это делает.